# Java decryption on an app, decompiled source code

Tags: java

After examining this code for a few hours a have the slightest idea as to what's going on, but I come from python and this is totally different.

I just looked up basic stuff like StringBuilder and can understand that as its simple. This may be a simple hashing algorithm to some, but this is the first time I've ever attempted something like `public final String getSignature(String paramString1, String paramString2)`, this is the method/function I partially understand. It gets the email and timestamp and adds them to a string builder with :.

However this (what i think at least) couldn't be the only function needed to create the signature used on the request, so this brings me to my next question what are all the other functions doing, like why in the first function does it append `""` to a `StringBuilder`, that seems pointless to me, and what is ParamString in the first function.

My overall question is just how does this work? I have looked at this code for at least 2 hours with what I feel as no progress. Things like `Charset charset = Charsets.UTF_8;` are definitely self explanatory, but things such as `Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(arrayOfByte2, "(this as java.lang.String).getBytes(charset)");` aren't and are very hard to understand.

This is all the code in the file `Signature.class` , so i am sure this is all of the code. I am not asking for a breakdown of everything. What i am most confused on is how the arguments are being used on the methods/functions. How can i tell for instance what String paramString is in `public Signature(String paramString)`. I know i have asked many questions throughout this, but this is the one I want answered the most. I also have 0 experience in any sort of hashes.

Only type of encoding I can use easily is base64 and its not like that is really for security it's just a universal language for dbs. Im trying to stray away from learning another language just for this one thing, but I also feel that this could definitely help me with other things throughout my future years. This is also the first time I have ever decompiled something.

````
package com.loke.tidy.rest;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Formatter;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import kotlin.TypeCastException;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import kotlin.text.Charsets;

public final class Signature {
  private byte[] key;

  public Signature(String paramString) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("");
    stringBuilder.append(paramString);
    stringBuilder.append(":f780e905a457f84ffc7c1d5d953bc0d2");
    this.key = getSha1(stringBuilder.toString());
  }

  private final byte[] createHmac(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte1, byte[] paramArrayOfbyte2, String paramString) {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(paramArrayOfbyte2, paramString);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(paramString);
    mac.init(secretKeySpec);
    paramArrayOfbyte1 = mac.doFinal(paramArrayOfbyte1);
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(paramArrayOfbyte1, "mac.doFinal(data)");
    return paramArrayOfbyte1;
  }

  private final String toHexString(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    int j = paramArrayOfbyte.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      formatter.format("%02x", new Object[] { Byte.valueOf(paramArrayOfbyte[i]) });
    } 
    String str = formatter.toString();
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(str, "formatter.toString()");
    return str;
  }

  public final byte[] getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }

  public final byte[] getSha1(String paramString) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(paramString, "text");
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] arrayOfByte2 = paramString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(arrayOfByte2, "(this as java.lang.String).getBytes(charset)");
    messageDigest.update(arrayOfByte2, 0, paramString.length());
    byte[] arrayOfByte1 = messageDigest.digest();
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(arrayOfByte1, "md.digest()");
    return arrayOfByte1;
  }

  public final String getSignature(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(paramString1, "email");
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(paramString2, "timestamp");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("");
    stringBuilder.append(paramString2);
    stringBuilder.append(':');
    stringBuilder.append(paramString1);
    paramString1 = stringBuilder.toString();
    Charset charset = Charsets.UTF_8;
    if (paramString1 == null)
      throw new TypeCastException("null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.String"); 
    byte[] arrayOfByte = paramString1.getBytes(charset);
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(arrayOfByte, "(this as java.lang.String).getBytes(charset)");
    return toHexString(createHmac(arrayOfByte, this.key, "HmacSHA1"));
  }

  public final void setKey(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(paramArrayOfbyte, "<set-?>");
    this.key = paramArrayOfbyte;
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a class for generating MAC's (Message Authentication Codes) ... loosely, digital signatures.  The API provides:

- A constructor that instantiates a `Signature` with user supplied string that is combined with a "magic number" and used to generate a key.
- A public method for generating a signature for (apparently) an email (or email address) and a timestamp.  The signature is encoded as a hexadecimal string.
- A public method for generating SHA1 hashes of text.  This is used internally.  It may have been exposed in the API by accident or deliberately.

How does it work?

Well the important parts are simply calls to standard Java crypto classes; e.g. an SHA1 digest creator and a HMAC generator.  (A HMAC is a hash based MAC.)  You should be able to figure out what is going on by reading the javadocs for the respective classes, and comparing them to the way they are being used:

- `java.crypto.Mac` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html))
- `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html))

and so on.

The mysterious stuff involving `Intrinsics` can be safely ignored (IMO).  It appears that this Java code is actually decompiled Kotlin code.  The calls into `Intrinsics` are implementing various runtime checks on Kotlin arguments and values.  For example, my *guess* is that the calls to `checkExpressionValueIsNotNull` will check that the first argument is not null.  If it is `null`, it will probably throw an exception which includes the second argument in the exception message.  (You could probably chase this down, but I doubt that it is worth the effort.)

---

> This is also the first time I have ever decompiled something.

You are better off looking at the original Kotlin source code.  Understanding decompiled code typically involves a degree of guesswork to figure out what variables are / mean and unpick possible mistakes and unintuitive translations in the decompiled code.  You also need to be able to read the decompiler's target language.  In this case Java.

It is a lot easier to read the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

You have decompiled bytecode that was the result of compiling Kotlin source code, not java source code. Basically these Intrinsics calls check whether the first argument is null; if it is, then it throws an exception with a message that contains the second argument. It would be better to read the original source code rather than trying to de online.